# Enemy movement just on some portion of ground 2D Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can I make my enemy move just on some suspended blocks? I have a script but my enemy fall of them and doesn't stop when is not any block around . I am bound to put blocks higher just to stop his fall?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float latestDirectionChangeTime;
    private readonly float directionChangeTime = 3f;
    private float characterVelocity = 2f;
    private Vector2 movementDirection;
    private Vector2 movementPerSecond;


    void Start()
    {
        latestDirectionChangeTime = 0f;
        calcuateNewMovementVector();
    }

    void calcuateNewMovementVector()
    {
        //create a random direction vector with the magnitude of 1, later multiply it with the velocity of the enemy
        movementDirection = new Vector2(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f)).normalized;
        movementPerSecond = movementDirection * characterVelocity;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //if the changeTime was reached, calculate a new movement vector
        if (Time.time - latestDirectionChangeTime > directionChangeTime)
        {
            latestDirectionChangeTime = Time.time;
            calcuateNewMovementVector();
        }

        //move enemy: 
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + (movementPerSecond.x * Time.deltaTime),
        transform.position.y + (movementPerSecond.y * Time.deltaTime));

    }
}
```

Comment: have you considered just adding triggers that your enemys turn round when they hit them?

Comment: the player doesn't collide with them too?

Comment: Triggers are that. So in ontrigger on your enemy turn round.  On player, if you dont need triggers dont have an ontrigger, or, assign them a tag of say platformboundary and ignore them... or...